# Locking piece of code in python

Tags: python, multithreading, machine-learning, locking, global-variables

I have a function which contains critical block/piece of code responsible for accessing a resource loaded in a global variable. I would like to lock this critical code block, as my function gets executed multiple times simultaneously.

What I am trying to avoid is the resource generating some results from data from first function call and a second function taking this result, as the resource takes some time to execute.

```
global_var = SomeMachineLearningModel

def famousFunction():
    # some initializations here
    # here also

    critical_results = global_var.use() # May take few seconds to complete

    # some critical_results manipulation
    return manipulated_results
```

Would locking critical_results within the function be a good solution or locking the entire function body?

There are no threads being used, I would just like this global_variable to be accessed by one function call at a time, or may be the entire function.

I am not sure which locking method to use.

Thanks !!

EDIT:
The race condition would occur when the first function call would be waiting for the model(machine learning model) to produce a result and the second function call also be waiting and when the first result arrives it is consumed by the wrong function call.

Comment: Do you mean you want to cache what `global_var.use()` returns between function calls?

Comment: "There are no threads being used" please explain... if this is the case, the only issue I can conceive of is this global variable being called by a recursive function multiple times (which would just cause deadlock if you lock it)

Comment: @DuncanWP if first call to famousFunction() is supposed to generate 10 and second call is supposed to generate 20, I want the answer of the first call to be delivered as 10 and not get to second function which maybe executed simultaneous. As this global_var.use() is globally available to both. (It is a machine learning model loaded from a file directory)

Comment: You need to explain the "simultaneous" part. If your application is not multithreaded, then do you have multiple processes running?

Comment: @Aaron Yes I am not using any threads explicitly. I am a noob at python, is there a way I can call this function just once at a time and wait until the output is produced, and then accept another function call ?

Comment: @bogatron Multiple api get requests are executing this function together. Are those considered as threads too ? Sorry I am not aware of this.

Comment: If you don't have multiple threads or multiple processes, It's not possible for any of your code to execute out of order.

Comment: are the api calls blocking or asynchronous? and example of blocking would be `value = someresource.get(params)` non blocking would probably look like: `someresource.request(params); value=someresource.get()`

Comment: @Aaron Would api get requests be considered as threads ? If yes, I will update the question right away.

Comment: @Aaron they are asynchronous

Comment: what's the api? they often include guidelines on how to make them threadsafe if they are asynchronous..

Comment: @Aaron I am working on a REST api, and the software I would be integrating with does around 5 to 7 requests per second. Maybe you could tell me about these guidelines in python that I should look into ?

Comment: Guidelines would be written by the author of the api. I think I'm still not quite clear on what you're getting at. Could you edit your question to describe how this race condition would occur?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144937/discussion-between-aaron-and-deepdebugging).

Comment: @Aaron edited and sure.

Answer (score 0):

Note: For my answer, I will be going with the assumption the famousFunction function is being called in a multithreaded environment or asynchronously.

I would recommend using a context manager and some kind of file lock / mutex. There are likely libraries that provide a cleaner solution to file locking than my example below.

```
import os

class Lock:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    def __enter__(self):
        if os.path.exists(self.filename):
            print('Method locked! Try again later.')
            return
        open(self.filename, 'a').close()

    def __exit__(self):
        os.remove(self.filename)
```

Then, in your famousFunction function:

```
with Lock('tempfile'):
    critical_results = global_var.use()
```

With this simplified example, be aware of exceptions and long running functions that may not release the lock.